# Cannot set property after Get reques - Axios and HTML5 datalist

Tags: vuejs2, axios, html-datalist

I am trying to do a GET request using Axios , but get the following error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'films' of undefined
at eval (SearchBar.vue?e266:26)
```

> SearchBar.vue

```
    <template>
    <section>
        <input v-model='film' type='text' list='films'>
  <datalist id='films'>
    <option v-for='film in films' :key='film.episode_id'>{{film}}</option>
  </datalist>
    </section>
    </template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  data() {
    return {
      film: "",
      films: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("https://swapi.co/api/films/")
      .then(function(response) {
        // handle success
        //console.log(response);
        this.films = response.data.results;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Anyone can tell me why I get the error? Note: I am running this locally for instant prototyping via Vue-Cli

Comment: The error is prettry clear, your `films` property is `undefined`. Try to add some details, try to console.log your axios response. I think `response.data.results` is `undefined` then when your `films` is used inside your loop, it fail.

Comment: Looks like I can't use 'this' without using fat arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One way is to use Arrow function:

```js
created() {
  axios
    .get("https://swapi.co/api/films/")
    .then((response) => {
      // handle success
      //console.log(response);
      this.films = response.data.results;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

2. Another way `that = this` & then use `that` inside promise callback

```js
created() {
  const that = this; // <-- assign this in that

  axios
    .get("https://swapi.co/api/films/")
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      //console.log(response);
      that.films = response.data.results;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```